# How to ground Raspberry in a car

Tags: pi-zero-w-2

I want to use Raspberry Zero 2W with cam in my car. I always feel electrostatic when I went out from cars. How should I protect Raspberry and a cam from electrostatic in my car? What parts of car I can use to connect to rasp ground? Should I use electrostatic films to protect a cam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common way to ground car electronics is to connect it to car's body/engine block/negative battery terminal. All three are usually connected. You may use multimeter to check it.

Depending on where your Pi withdraws power from it might be already grounded "properly". E.g. 12V socket is expected to have negative terminal grounded so it is likely that negative terminal in your 5V adapter connected to the socket will be at the same potential. Again, multimeter will be a good way to check.

Lastly, it is not recommended to use duplicating ground connections (e.g. connecting additional grounding cable to Pi's GND pin in case it is already grounded at the same potential already) to avoid so called ground loops.

Comment: Since you did not state what car you have there were some that had a positive ground. Mostly they were 6V systems. If it is an older car check to be sure. an example would be a stock 1955 Ford.